# How can I combine two object in one of the object in RxJava?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have Data and DataDetail classes, each of them contains data that neighter of them 
don’t contain.
I have List class which I fetch from backend,
having Data which has id field  I can request DataDetail, and DataDetail have some info which in Data object are null, so I can get from DataDetail and set in Data class .

```
`fetchData()
.toFlowable()
.flatMapIterable(datas->datas).map(new Function<Data, Flowable<DataDetail>>() { @Override  public Flowable<DataDetail>`apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Data data) throws Exception { return
```

`fetchDataDetail(data()).toFlowable();   } })
.map(new Function<DataDetail, Flowable<Data>>() {
 @Override  
public Flowable<DataDetail> apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull DataDetail dataDetail) throws Exception { 

return //I want to have access data and dataDetail object   } })
.toList();`

.map() ? in map as argument I get DataDetail  object which is Flowable,
Flowable  but I need to have access both Data and DataDetail  to get some data from DataDetail and set in Data object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is what your api is returning.

```
api.getList() // this returns a Single<List<Data>>
```

If that is correct may be this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
Single<List<Pair<Data,Detail>>> dataSingle = api.getList()
    .toFlowable()
    .flatMap(Flowable::fromIterable) // Convert the list to single emissions
    .flatMap(data -> {
            // Make api call to get details 
            return api.getDetails(data.getId())
                .flatMap(dataDetails -> {
                    return Flowable.just(Pair.create(data,dataDetail));
                });
        }).toList();
```

And obviously if you need to convert that to `Flowable` , you can easily do that with `toFlowable`.

The `Pair` is from `android.support.v4.util.Pair`. Ideally you create a separate model to represent the data from `data` and `detail` instead. But as a quick hack you can use `Pair`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks ,but then having Single<List<Pair<Data,Detail>>>
I don't know how to move forward, get data from detail and set in data object ?

Comment: With the Pair you have both the data. You can decide how you want to  mutated the `Data` object.  Or as I suggested consider creating a new model. Lets call the new model `UiFeed`. then you can create a method called `createUiModel(Data data, DataDetails details)`. In that method create the `UiModel` with all the relevant properties that matter to you.

Comment: Or alternatively if for some reason you really want to mutate the data object,  you can do that in the `.flatMap(dataDetails -> { data.setYourField(dataDetail.getYourField()) ` and then return  `Flowable.just(data)` instead of returning a pair.